# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, mysql, django

It's a django project,the views.py is

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.db import connection

def get_cursor():
    return connection.cursor

def index(request):
    cursor = get_cursor()
    cursor.execute("select id,name,author from book")
    books = cursor.fetchall()

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Few minutes, it's work, but now error, and it can not get data from mysql,I don't know if is my system fault.

Comment: Apart from the error in `get_cursor()` - you didn't call the `connection.cursor` method - why are you doing this at all? Why aren't you using the Django model layer, especially for such a simple query?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm learning for django, this step didn't use Model. In the function of index, I used 'cursor = get_cursor()', was it not call the 'connection.cursor'?

Comment: But that is not the way to learn Django. The way to do that is to follow the tutorial, which starts with defining models. And no, you need to *call* it inside the function: `return connection.cursor()`.

Comment: @Daniel I change it ,but there is a new error:'django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2026, 'SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_tmp_dh failed')'